# Question on even, odd complex valued function

Tags: complex-analysis, even-and-odd-functions

I was solving following multiple choice question (more than one options may be correct) on complex analysis.

**Question**: The function $f(z)=z^2$ where $0 \leq \arg(z) \leq \pi$ is **not**

(a) even

(b) odd

(c) The one about which nothing can be said

(d) both even and odd

**My attempt** since elements of domain on $f$ must satisfies $0 \leq \arg(z) \leq \pi$. So we must consider the numbers in lower half plane say $z=a-bi$ is in lower half plane, so that we have $b>0$ then $-z=-a+bi$ will be in the upper half plane and so that its Principal Argument satisfies $0 \leq \arg(z) \leq \pi$. Hence we can operate $f$ on $-z$. Clearly $f(-z)=(-z)^2 =(-a+bi)^2=(-a+bi)(-a+bi)=a^2-b^2-2abi$

On other hand, $f(z)=z^2=(a-bi)^2=a^2-b^2-2abi$ so we see that $f(-z)=f(z)$ for all $z$ that satisfies $0 \leq \arg(z) \leq \pi$ and hence $f$ will be even function?

But answer key says I was wrong. Please help me.

Comment: If $z$ is in the upper halfplane then $-z$ is in the lower halfplane and $f(-z)$ is *not defined.*

Comment: The domain $0 \le Arg(z) \le \pi$ is the upper half plane, including the real axis. The function is even on the real axis, and there are no other $z$ such that both $z$ and $-z$ are in the domain.

Comment: @MartinR sir, so domain of the exclude the upper half plane?

Comment: @dxiv sir if domain is the upper half plane including the real axis then how can we consider $f(-z)$? I mean when $z$ is in upper half plane then $-z$ will be in lower half plane and so that $0≤Arg(z)<π$ does not holds. Please help

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi The usual definition of an even/odd function requires the domain to be symmetric about $0$. Yours is not. What definition of even/odd functions are you supposed to use?

Comment: @dxiv sir so what will be the answer?  (a), (b), (d)?  that is given function is Not even, Not odd, Not both even and odd?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi Definitely (b) and (d). Whether (a) and/or (c) depends on "*what definition of even/odd functions are you supposed to use*", which you have not clarified, yet.

Comment: @dxiv sir, I am using the usual definition of even/ odd function. $f$ is said to be even function if $f(-z)=f(z)$ for all $z$ in domain of $f$ and $f$ is said to odd function if $f(-z)=-f(z)$ for all $z$ in the domain. So in this case (a), (c) are correct or not?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi That's not a complete definition. There may be $z$ in the domain where $-z$ is *not* in the domain, so the equalities $f(-z)=\pm f(z)$ are not even defined for some $z$ in the domain. You must clarify what *your* definition is, and what it says about *those* cases. FWIW this looks like a question meant to verify that you really know what definitions of even/odd you are working with.